# Laravel 5.5 Role Management

Tags: laravel-5

I'm learning Laravel, and implementing a user system to my site.

I can't figure out how to add roles, and manage them.

If anybody has any good guides, or can directly help me, I'd be extremely appreciative.

Comment: Have a look [Associate users with roles and permissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

Comment: Looking now @MKhalidJunaid cheers mate. Also can't post another question for 90 minutes, however I wonder if you can help. I set up a custom Middleware to check for Beta Tester Role.

However, this middleware seems to only be applying to my register page, but not Home or Login. (needs to only apply to home.

How do i do this?

Comment: In controller you want to apply role, define it area by middleware. for example:   

 `public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout']]);
    }`